# send ems messages from pc to mobile

Tags: java, sms-gateway, ems

i am in search of a java api/ library/ sms-gateway that supports sending of EMS messages from pc to mobile. By EMS, i basically mean sending concatenated messages, picture messages(1 bit images), short audio clips(iMelody format).

Earlier, i used [smslib](http://smslib.org/) to send a simple text message. Later i came to know it does not support EMS messages.

Then I found out [smsj](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/index.html) which supports this. But implementing this gave me lots of problems. i tried it by connecting a gsm modem, gave me `connection failed at at+cmgf` error. tried by using [clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/), but again had connection issues while connecting to the server, even though i had a working internet connection.

I have searched a lot on google for other libraries supporting this, but all in vain. 
If there are any other libraries supporting this, could you please specify their links?

Help in any way will be really appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ozeki NG SMS gateway. I tried it long back for integrating SMS. But, it is found that we can send special formats too such as EMS. But the tool is proprietary and gives you 20 days trial.

http://www.sms-integration.com/compatibility-issues-in-sms-systems-63.html

http://www.ozekisms.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use gcm but that is for android. Well it is a push notification service from google

Here is the link

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

But I think its capacity is very low

Pushwoosh is there to cover all the platforms

http://www.pushwoosh.com/

Once see this

These both are not sms getways , these are push notification services

But according to your requirement they may help you.......

Comment: i looked at it. but i need to send proper messages. not push notifications.

Comment: @newtoandroid but for that you have to get some paid service. Because no one will give it for free now. In android also if you want to do so just send push notification read the content and add it to the sms inbox and give a notification to the user